# How to use the jar files from Maven Central Repository?

Tags: maven

I'm learning DataFX, and [DataFX download](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.javafxdata%22) shows tutorial links on Maven Central Repository.
Why those tutorial、samples are all jar files?

I'm not very familiar with Maven. I know Maven can help library maintaining by download the jars which project needs.

On [DataFX download](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.javafxdata%22), the tutorial-sources.jar contains only source code, so it's not a library, right?

I will ask the manager of DataFX too, but I just want to try some luck here.

It looks like I need to unjar the tutorial.jar manually to get the source code.

My Question is: Do I misunderstand about the whole thing? the usage of [DataFX download](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.javafxdata%22) is not the common use (for library maintain)? 
Instead, I should just ask the project manager how to use these stuff ?

Comment: maven downloads all dependency jars to your local repo.

Comment: In order to study the tutorial, I have to unjar the files, right? Can Maven unjar those jars to source code from Maven Central Repository in simple commands? or I have to download the jars and unjar manually?

Comment: maven is open source. you can find the source in GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is tool for managing dependencies. If you want to create new application that depends on some library, you should speficy it on `pom.xml` like this. Then maven download it from `Maven Central` or somewhere and you can build your application.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javafxdata</groupId>
    <artifactId>datafx-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you don't have pom.xml, you need to create new maven project. See maven tutorial for more information. You need several hours to be familiar with it.

Comment: Thank for your response.  Since   [DataFX download](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.javafxdata%22) provides pom.xml、tutorial.jar、tutorial-source.jar, Can I use maven command to recover all these 3 files back to an uncompile project? Or I still have to create a new Maven project, and unjar the source.jar manually?